# APEX Line of Best Fit

Tags: sql, oracle, charts, oracle-apex

im trying to plot Line of Best Fit on my apex chart.
The problem is, i need to do it dynamically, not trough XML (i mean, i can (but shouldn't) just plot the line directly in XML).
Here is the result of SQL, which later create points on my Scatter Chart:

```
S       F       P       V
1.09    1   0.02326 -1.32474
1.1     2   0.06977 -0.97930
1.13    1   0.09302 -0.86496
1.14    3   0.16279 -0.59624
1.15    2   0.20930 -0.44723
```

Here is how this chart should look like-ish
[image: My APEX Chart]

The thing is, i need to build a line of best fit, and i cant to do this through SQL.

Here is the initial SQL, to get data, which i've provided on top of this topic:

```
SELECT 
  ROUND(sum(cny) over(ORDER BY ny) / ('&P8_COUNT.' +1),6) p,
  cny f,
  ny s,
  ROUND(-ln(ABS(ln(ROUND(sum(cny) over(ORDER BY ny) / ('&P8_COUNT.' +1),6)))),5) v
FROM
  (SELECT ny,count(ny) cny
   FROM
     (SELECT t.ny
      FROM test.test4 t
      WHERE COMMENT LIKE '% &P8_DATA./%'
        OR COMMENT LIKE '% 0&P8_DATA./%'
      ORDER BY date DESC)
   GROUP BY ny)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 30
```

Is there any way, to plot this line directly from SQL, and not manually?

**P.S. Here is the example how to build it directly in XML:** [AnyChart.com Scatter Graph Charts](http://anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/Samples/sample-scatter-graph-charts.html#xml-code)

Answer (score 2):

There is only one option, its the one you suggested already:

- Build the XML dynamically via an Application Process in combination of a AJAX Request (that't what we do mostly for our more complex productive applications)
- Using the 2. data series as a second source for a line doesn't work as the data source is fixed if you use the default APEX form for building graphs for AnyChart